# Yii2 ajax validation not work

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation, yii2

I was trying to validate my YII2 register form but it not work. In view:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id'                   => 'register',
    'options'              => ['accept-charset'=>'utf-8'],
    'validateOnChange'     => false,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validateOnSubmit'     => true,
])
```

In controller:

```
$model = new MUser();

if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
{
    $model->refresh();
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
elseif($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
{
    \\do something
}
```

In Model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
               [
                   'username', 
                   'unique', 
                   'targetClass' => 'com\modules\admin\models\MUser',
                   'message'     => 'Username exist',
               ]
           ];
}
```

Can anyone let me know what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Show `com\modules\admin\models\MUser` model

Comment: Did you prepare according controller for returning correct response in case of AJAX request? Show controller code.

Comment: try 'enableClientValidation'=> false

Comment: Muser model: public function rules()
    {
        return [
    ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass'=>'com\modules\admin\models\MUser',
                'message'=>'Username exist')]
     ];

    }

Comment: I think it not work because  if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
        {
            $model->refresh();
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

When I remove this code, it register user form work correctly but didn't check username unique, sorry for my bad English

Comment: try 
1. Match basic required and require-dev section in composer.json file only. If you using basic match with basic if advance then use advance
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/composer.json
2. then rm -rf vendor (remove vendor dir. make a backup first)
3. composer clear-cache
4. composer update -v
5. They moved jquery assets under bower. Please check what you are using.

Comment: 6. Try print_r() die; of validation and see if the validation is returning any error. Check this in console

Comment: Which problem do you actually have? Error? Unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
return ActiveForm::validate($model)
```

TO

```
 echo json_encode(ActiveForm::validate($model));
        \Yii::$app->end();
```

`ActiveForm::validate($model)` is an array it needs to be represented in json form which is done by json_encode and `\Yii::$app->end()`; is making sure that the application stop on just checking.Also make sure you have after the namespace :

```
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```

But By doing so the submission via ajax of your form will not work the perfect way is using validationUrl.